# How can I convert all .webm files in a folder to .m4a or .mp3?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, command-prompt, webm, m4a

I have a folder filled with .webm and .m4a files.

Is there a way, using either Windows Command Prompt or a Python script, to convert all of the .webm files to .m4a OR to convert all .webm files AND .m4a files to .mp3 files?

I've tried using FFmpeg, but that only works for single files.

How would I use this to mass convert all of the .webm files to .m4a files in a given folder/directory, if possible?
If not, is there another library I can use to do this?

Comment: I think this is too generic, you should try to find yourself first and then ask here if you have any specific problems.

Comment: Windows batch files know a "for" command which may be enough to iterate through the files and call "ffmpeg" for each. Read documentation about bat files and ffmpeg for details.